# How to add date and time to filename in javascript function for adobe pro file?

Tags: javascript, adobe

I would like to get the date and time to append to the filename of a pdf file when it is saved.

Here is the function used for saving the file when a button is clicked:

```
mySaveAs = app.trustPropagatorFunction(function(doc,path)
{
app.beginPriv();
doc.saveAs(path);
app.endPriv();
})

myTrustedSpecialTaskFunc = app.trustedFunction(function(doc,path)
{
// Privileged and/or non-privileged code above
app.beginPriv();
mySaveAs(doc,path);
app.endPriv();
// Privileged and/or non-privileged code below
});
```

Here is the code for the button (mouseup):

```
myTrustedSpecialTaskFunc(this, "/F/signedcontracts/signeddoc.pdf");
```

I would like to have the filename in the following format:

> /F/signedcontracts/signeddocyyyymmddhhmmss.pdf

I have read through and tried several examples, but I'm still unable to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.  I just added a date time function:

```
function myDateSTring(){
return util.printd("yyyymmdd_HHMMss", new Date());
}

mySaveAs = app.trustPropagatorFunction(function(doc,path)
{
app.beginPriv();
doc.saveAs(path);
app.endPriv();
})

myTrustedSpecialTaskFunc = app.trustedFunction(function(doc,path)
{
// Privileged and/or non-privileged code above
app.beginPriv();
mySaveAs(doc,path);
app.endPriv();
// Privileged and/or non-privileged code below
});
```

Then I modified the button script to:

```
myTrustedSpecialTaskFunc(this, "/F/signedcontracts/signed-doc-jlf"+myDateSTring()+".pdf");
```